# How do I get primary key of colliding row on failed insert?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

After I try to insert a row into database and it fails due to duplicate (not primary key collision - another key), how do I get the primary key of the colliding row that prevented the insert?

Example:
The table:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `unique_value` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `unique_data` (`unique_values`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Some initial data:

```
INSERT INTO `my_table`(`unique_value`) VALUES ('unique string 1');
INSERT INTO `my_table`(`unique_value`) VALUES ('unique string 2');
```

And now, this will fail because of the collision in the index:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `my_table`(`unique_value`) VALUES 'unique string 2'";
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Can I get the primary key of the colliding row without making another query?

Answer (score 0):

while creating the table you can use "Identity" keyword which will do all the "not null and Auto Increment" Stuff.
But this is for MsSQL
Try this:

```
create table my_table
(
    ID int Primary key identity,
    unique_value varchar(60) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Primary key is not the issue here. The collision is on another key. I want to get the primary key of the colliding row.

Answer (score 0):

As you said this that you are not worry about PK hence you can check the value of the column which has unique index.If there is already a raw with the value that you passing in new row then you are trying to insert duplicate otherwise not.